# How can I get a separate reference to each version/artifact of the same published java package, in one JVM (stack = sbt + scala)?

Tags: scala, maven, reflection, jvm, sbt

I am considering building a small tool for running regression testing to find regressions in data between two releases of the same project.

So far, i can import the project, and can even import both versions without compilation failures.

```
name := "diffing-tool"

val sparkVersion = "3.1.2"
resolvers += Resolver.publishMavenLocal
resolvers += Resolver.defaultLocal
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "com.foo" %% "bar" % "1.0",
  "com.foo" %% "bar" % "1.1"

)
```

My code can compile and run the following code

```
object Hello extends App {
  println("Hello world")
  val fromJar1 = com.foo.bar.Run.main()
  val fromJar2 = com.foo.bar.Run.main()

  def diff(fromJar1: Any, fromJar2: Any) = {
    println("Hello world")
  }

  diff(fromJar1, fromJar2)
}
```

However, I do not know a good way to rename the packages/artifacts such that the code can refer to each version of the code separately.

Ideas of what this would look like include

1. the use of shading in the `build.sbt` file (which is usually used for dependencies of dependencies, and I have not yet figured out what to do in my current use case -- also, i would like to avoid `sbt assembly` if possible which is coupled with shading if i am not mistaken). ill need detailed instructions on how to set this up.
2. Another approach is, at runtime, to use `reflection`, the `ClassLoader`, or perhaps something from the `sbt.librarymanagement` package, to get a separate reference to each artifact. Will need detailed instructions on how to set this up.
3. Other ideas are very welcome.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: The purpose is to conduct regression testing: Comparing results between releases..

Comment: This would be much easier to achieve by running the same tests for two version in **separate JVMs**.

Comment: _can even import both versions without compilation failures_. Are you sure of that? I would bet SBT evict the older version and keep only the recent one.

Comment: Anyway I agree with has been suggested by Fabian: it will be way much easier to run each version isolated and compare as part of another process. If it makes sense in your context, I would look into the container direction as well to spin up each version in its isolated environment.

Comment: Correct, there is eviction.

Comment: I will try shading and  sbt.librarymanagement for now.